# Does Microsoft Azure keep a log of IP Addresses visited by a Virtual Machine?

Tags: azure, ip-address

I have created a VM on Azure using the OpenVPN image from the Azure Marketplace and intend to use it as my VPN instead of my current VPN; ExpressVPN.

I know that ExpressVPN has a no logs policy.

I am wondering if somewhere in Azure a log of sites I visit using my new VPN would/could be kept?

Googling for the answer has led me nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you are doing inside a VM - and running some OpenVPN server certainly falls under that - is totally up to you. That also means that any logging you would like to do, is totally up to you to implement.

That said: Since you are using some Marketplace image (and I assume that is not one provided by Microsoft), you should check what exactly the image contains and does (this generally applies when using any Marketplace image). However, even if there would be some logging prepared in that VM, without you specifying a connection to something like Azure Monitor, the answer to your question is: No, Azure does not store data like that.

Comment: Thank you @silent I thought that is probably the case. BTW for the wonderers "I am not doing anything neferious". Just curious.